# How can I prepare a sparkline graph (line/bar)?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I prepare a `SPARKLINE` graph (line/bar) in a Google Sheets?

With the Google Drive help it doesn't work for me.

Reference: [Google Drive Help](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2371371).

Comment: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sparklines-in-google-sheets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to address a line/bar type graph. Consider the following data set:

```
A1:A5 = data
B1 = charttype, C1 = bar
```

---

First:

```
SPARKLINE(A1:A5;B1:C1)
```

*Take a good look at the semicolon, in stead off the comma !!*

---

Secondly:

```
SPARKLINE(A1:A5;{"charttype"\"bar"})
```

*Take a good look at the backslash, in stead off the comma !!*

---

Without these two modifications, making `SPARKLINE` graphs became very difficult for me.

Please note, that these changes may only be affected by CEST/CET time zones, see remark made by Adah (google) in the second reference.

References:

1. [Google Group discussion](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/QzVhyW5bi-A)
2. [Google Drive Help](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2371371)